# hive user insert, but hdfs permission denied

Tags: hive, insert, hdfs, permission-denied

The admin user of my hive is named **appuser**.I have create a database named wuchang_test and a table named abtestmsg.
Yes , I describe the database, the OWNER NAME of this database is appuser and OWNER TYPE is USER ,just like below:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://hive.data.ms.netease.com:1000> describe database wuchang_test;
OK
db_name|comment|location|owner_name|owner_type|parameters
wuchang_test||hdfs://datahdfsmaster/hive/warehouse/wuchang_test.db|appuser|USER|
```

I have defined a role named **ep_dm** and a user named **bjchenweiyao** of this role;  Also , I have already grant SELECT,DELETE,UPDATE,INSERT of this table to role ep_dm:

```
database|table|partition|column|principal_name|principal_type|privilege|grant_option|grant_time|grantor

wuchang_test|abtestmsg|||appuser|USER|DELETE|true|1498113549000|appuser
wuchang_test|abtestmsg|||appuser|USER|INSERT|true|1498113549000|appuser
wuchang_test|abtestmsg|||appuser|USER|SELECT|true|1498113549000|appuser
wuchang_test|abtestmsg|||appuser|USER|UPDATE|true|1498113549000|appuser
wuchang_test|abtestmsg|||ep_dm|ROLE|DELETE|false|1498113687000|appuser
wuchang_test|abtestmsg|||ep_dm|ROLE|INSERT|false|1498113696000|appuser
wuchang_test|abtestmsg|||ep_dm|ROLE|SELECT|false|1498113704000|appuser
wuchang_test|abtestmsg|||ep_dm|ROLE|UPDATE|false|1498113712000|appuser
```

user bjchenweiyao tried to insert some data to table wuchang_test.abtestmsg, but permission denied:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: RuntimeException Cannot create staging directory 'hdfs://datahdfsmaster/hive/warehouse/wuchang_test.db/abtestmsg/dt=2017-05-01/.hive-staging_hive_2017-06-22_14-55-58_843_8091260031059700585-336': Permission denied: user=bjchenweiyao, access=WRITE, inode="/hive/warehouse/wuchang_test.db/abtestmsg/dt=2017-05-01/.hive-staging_hive_2017-06-22_14-55-58_843_8091260031059700585-336":appuser:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
```

In order to make user bjchenweiyao to have the write permission for table wuchang_test.abtestmsg, I alter the database owner from USER appuser to ROLE ep_dm:

```
alter database wuchang_test set owner ROLE ep_dm;
```

or I alter the database owner from USER appuser to USER bjchenweiyao directly:

```
alter database wuchang_test set owner USER bjchenweiyao;
```

both those methods have tried, but the permission problem is still there.

the database hdfs directory permission is :

```
[appuser@hz-105 ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /hive/warehouse/wuchang_test.db
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - appuser supergroup          0 2017-06-22 14:39 /hive/warehouse/wuchang_test.db/abtestmsg
```

I know , the user bjchenweiyao has no permission to write to hdfs directory /hive/warehouse/wuchang_test.db/abtestmsg whose permission is drwxr-xr-x .

But what can I do to make bjchenweiyao has the write permission?

Comment: You would need a security manager like Sentry or Ranger to align the HDFS privileges to the Hive privileges; otherwise you have to manage the HDFS privileges yourself: provided that your HDFS config has the flag *_supports ACLs"_ raised, run something like `hdfs dfs -setfacl -R -m user:bjchenweiyao:rwx,default:user:bjchenweiyao:rwx /hive/warehouse/wuchang_test.db`

Comment: ...and be aware that there's a nasty bug in HDFS that affects the propagation of default privileges (fixed in Hadoop 3 only!) so you probably will have to correct the "mask" for all newly created directories and files, whenever you hit another error, with `hdfs dfs -setfacl -R -m mask::rwx /hive/warehouse/wuchang_test.db`

Comment: Yes , my hdfs system's ACL is disabled. I will test the ACL function in my test environment . I don't know if my hive、hbase 、kafka 、mapreduce jobs 、 spark jobs  and all other hdfs-based component will be affected if I enable the ACL.

Comment: With ACLs on, there is a very small overhead when opening the files (additional security checks in NameNode) and different kinds of "access denied" exceptions -- which makes things a little more difficult to debug.

Comment: My doubt is , when I switch on ACL ,before I add any ACLs , the file and directory permission is the same with that that when it is off? That is to say , when i switch it on , is there any influence on my hive、hbase and mapreduce/spark tasks?

Comment: You can set ACLs _in addition_ to the base HDFS permissions; but you don't have to. Just like you can set ACLs on a local Linux file/directory. Think of an ACL as an exception to the generic permission model ==> if you use ACLs to **grant** additional access to additional users/groups, no impact on base permissions; if you use ACLs to **deny** access to specific users/groups, then the base permissions will be restricted also, to remain consistent *(but that's an edge case)*

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the same issue but I had the same error message

> FAILED: RuntimeException Cannot create staging directory
>   'hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hive/warehouse/test_table/.hive-staging_hive_2018-09-23_12-51-51_755_5072249936804482657-1':
>   Permission denied: user=HADOOPUSR, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/user/hive/warehouse/test_table":hduser:supergroup:drwxrwxr-x

It stated that it does not have write permission on hdfs directory to create staging directory `/user/hive/warehouse/test_table` So I solved it using : `hdfs dfs -chmod 777 /user/hive/warehouse/test_table`

So try `hdfs dfs -chmod 777 /hive/warehouse/wuchang_test.db/abtestmsg`